# How to include a multi-document file using Helm library chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a very basic Helm library chart with only 1 file:

```
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
└── templates
    ├── _jobs.yaml
```

```
{{- define "library.jobs.tpl" -}}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-1
  ...
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-2
  ...
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-3
  ...
{{- end -}}
```

In the downstream chart, I use it like this in `library.yaml`:

```
{{- template "library.jobs" -}}
```

The issue is that `helm template` only renders the first document/object (`job-1`) and not the rest.

```
$ helm template -s templates/library.yaml .
---
# Source: mychart/templates/library.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-1
  ...
$
```

Why is that? Am I missing something or is this a potential bug in Helm?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
{{- define "library.jobs.tpl" -}}
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
```

So I was missing one `---` at the beginning of the template definition.